# Is an MPC protocol from ElGamal a good solution for homomorphic multiplication?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, elgamal-encryption, multiparty-computation

I want to compute a multiplication between many secret values and then distribute the result to everyone involved. For this, I thought about an MPC protocol built from Threshold Homomorphic Elgamal. All I need is :

- to protect parties secret values
- to compute the product homomorphically and obtain the result encrypted
- only the involved parties should be able to decrypt the obtained product

Is Elgamal secure enough for this context ?

As I have found from the description of the [Threshold Elgamal](http://www.win.tue.nl/~berry/2WC13/LectureNotes.pdf) pag. 64 and 66, it assumes an apriori distribution of the secret.

Comment: What adversarial model do you consider? How many of the involved parties may be corrupt? Are corrupt parties actively misbehaving or following the protocol honestly and just try to learn more than the output?